# How to get Search Service Application Paused state via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, search, administration

For maintenance you can do `Suspend-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication` and `Resume-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication`.

Besides the UI saying *Paused by system*, how do I figure out whether the SSA is currently paused?
`Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus` only returns active/online etc. I just can't easily find a property that tells me that the current crawl status is paused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command(s) to find out if the Search service application is paused

```
$ssa.IsPaused() -ne 0
```

MSDN Reference [Manage a paused Search service application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn745901.aspx)

Comment: do you have some more information on that? why do I have to check for 0, what does it tell me?

Comment: Please check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn745901.aspx